# Estimate volume of Tubes around a smooth hypersurface

Tags: measure-theory, differential-geometry

Suppose $\Sigma \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth compact hypersurface and the boundary of some set $\Omega$.  Now set $\Sigma_r:=\{x \in \Omega^c: \inf_{y\in \Sigma} |x-y|\leq r\}$ to be a tube of radius $r$ around the hypersurface. I was wondering if it is possible to somehow estimate the volume of these tubes in terms of the area of $\Sigma$, like for example
$$
vol(\Sigma_r) \leq C_{\Sigma} \cdot r \cdot area(\Sigma). 
$$
It should be possible for small $r$ due to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_distance_function) formula. There is of course a trivial bound like if I take some ball $B_R(y)$ such that $\Sigma \in B_R(y)$ then
$
vol(\Sigma_r) \leq vol(B_{R+r}(y)).
$
Is there something better?

Comment: Are you familiar with shape operators?

Comment: @DIdier_
Yes, is it possible to find compute the constant $C_{\Sigma}$ for large $r$ in terms of its eigenvalues?

Comment: Well, not exactly. I will post an answer because it is quite long.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, suppose that $\Omega$ is orientable and that $\nu$ is a unit normal vector field on $\Omega$ (in fact, a compact hypersurface in the euclidean spane is forced to be orientable). The map $(p,t)\in \Omega \times \mathbb{R} \to p+t\nu(p)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is smooth and its differential at a point $(p,0)$ is invertible. By compactness assumption and by the inverse function theorem, there exists $r_0>0$ such that it is a diffeomorphism from $\Omega\times (-r_0,r_0)$ onto its image that is the open tube around $\Omega$ with radius $r_0$.

Thus, we have a chart $f : \Omega \times (-r_0,r_0) \to \mathbb{R}^n$. If $\Sigma_r$ is the tube of radius $r$ around $\Omega$, then
$$
vol(\Sigma_r) = \int_{\Sigma_r} 1 ~\mathrm{d}vol_{eucl} = \int _{f^{-1}(\Sigma_r)}1 \left(f^*\mathrm{d}vol_{eucl}\right) = \int_{\Omega\times (-r,r)} 1 
\left(f^*\mathrm{d}vol_{eucl}\right)$$
Thus, it suffices to compute the voume form $\left(f^*\mathrm{d}vol_{eucl}\right)$ to have an estimate on the volume of $\Sigma_r$.

First of all, the volume form $\left(f^*\mathrm{d}vol_{eucl}\right)$ on $\Omega\times (-r_0,r_0)$ is proportionnal to the volume form $\mathrm{d}vol_{\Omega}\wedge \mathrm{d}t$ because the top bundle of a manifold is of rank $1$. Thus, there exists a positive function $\lambda(p,t)$ such that
$$
\left(f^*\mathrm{d}vol_{eucl}\right) = \lambda\cdot \mathrm{d}vol_{\Omega}\wedge \mathrm{d}t
$$
In every good Riemannian geometry book, you can find a proof of the following:
$$
\partial_t \lambda = \lambda \times \mathrm{trace}S
$$
where $S$ is the shape operator of the level hypersurface $\Omega_t = f\left( \Omega\times \{t\} \right)$. We are now reduced to evaluating the trace of $S$. But in every good Riemannian geometry book, there is this well known fact:
$$
\partial_t S = -S \circ S
$$
in the euclidean space (in general, one has to add a curvature term on the RHS): this is the Riccati equation for the shape operator. Taking the trace and using the fact that $\mathrm{trace}(S^2) \geqslant \frac{(\mathrm{trace}S)^2}{n-1}$, it follows that
$$
\partial_t\left(\frac{\mathrm{trace} S}{n-1}\right) + \left(\frac{\mathrm{trace}S}{n-1}\right)^2 \leqslant 0
$$
From this, one can recover some information on $\mathrm{trace}S$, then on $\lambda$ and finally, one can show an estimate on the volume of $\Sigma_r$.

**Note:** here are listed some good Riemannian geometry books :

- *Riemannian Geometry*, Gallot, Hulin, Lafontaine
- *Riemannian Geometry*, Petersen
- *Introduction to Riemannian manifolds*, Lee

One can find in them references for the above claims in the sections dedicated to extrinsic geometry and/or comparison estimates.

In some editions of Petersen's book, the function $\mathrm{trace}S$ does not appear explicitly; what is used is $\Delta r$, the Laplacian of $r$, where $r = d(\cdot,\Omega)$. But in fact this function is equal to $\mathrm{trace}S$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have two questions. You are computing the area of the hypersurfaces and then use the coarea formula to estimate the volume of the tube. Is there an easy way to see that the gradient of the distance function has norm one? And this only works for small radii $r$ right? Is there no way to compute the volume of tubes of very large $r$?

Comment: If you know about the Riemannian exponential map, the gradient of the distance function is just the radial derivative of the (normal) exponential map from $\Omega$: hence, starting from $\Omega$ with a unit normal vector field, the Gauss lemma says that it is everywhere unitary. For large $r$, this fails to work because this "polar" decomposition fails to be a diffeomorphism, and indeed, you can recover several times the same subset.

Comment: Moreover, this is not exactly the co-area formula, but just the definition of volume in a Riemannian manifold, that is, $vol(X) = \int_X \mathrm{d}vol_g$ where $X \subset (M,g)$ and of a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Thank you again. One final question. Do you know for what sets is it possible to do this for large $r$ aswell? I think convex sets should work because there is an unique minimizer of the distance function.

Comment: If $\Omega$ is compact orientable, it has an interior and an exterior, and for $r$ large, all the interior will be covered and the computation will not take account of that fact. What is true is if you restrict only to the exterior, you can compute the volume of the "exterior" tube as long as the "outward" exponential map is invertible. Some curvature conditions imply that: for example, if the sectionnal curvature outside $\Omega$ is non-positive and if $\Omega$ is (strictly?) convex, that is its shape operator is (definite?) positive.